# Spring MVC XML-less configuration exception : A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jetty

I'm new to Spring framework, trying my hands on Spring MVC xml-less (no web.xml or mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml) configuration, as that's what required for the project.

I get following error when I try to run it (using Jetty Local, again a project requirement)

Following is my config for replacing web.xml:

(Also tried extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` without luck)

```
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup( ServletContext servletContext ) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext rootContext = getContext(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext(ServletContext ctx) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    //Tried various combination of un/commenting following options.
    context.register( MvcServletConfig.class );
    //context.setConfigLocation("com.xyz.myapp.configuration");
    context.setServletContext( ctx );
    //context.refresh();
    //context.scan( "com.xyz.someapp.*" );
    return context;
}
}
```

This is my MVC/Servlet Config replacing mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xyz.myapp"})
public class MvcServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

public MvcServletConfig() { super(); }

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/login.jsp");
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return bean;
}
}
```

This is my AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xyz.myapp.*"})
@Import( { HibernateConfig.class } )
public class AppConfig {}
```

This is my HibernateConfig where in I have a static method that accesses the context:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan( {"com.obsm.visensia.configuration"} )
@PropertySources( value ={@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")} )
public class HibernateConfig {
@Transactional
public static void InitialiseDummyData()
{
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( AppConfig.class);
    AccountService accountService = (AccountService) context.getBean("accountService");
    if ( accountService != null )
    {
        Role admin = new AdminRole();
        Role serverAdmin = new ServerAdminRole();
        Role normal = new NormalRole();

        User adminUser = new User();
        adminUser.setFirstName( "Kunal" );
        adminUser.setLastName( "Patel" );
        adminUser.setSex( Sex.Male );
        adminUser.setUsername( "kp" );
        adminUser.setPassword( "kp" );
        adminUser.addRole( admin );


        accountService.addUser( adminUser );

        User serverAdminUser = new User();
        serverAdminUser.setFirstName( "Server" );
        serverAdminUser.setLastName( "Admin" );
        serverAdminUser.setSex( Sex.Male );
        serverAdminUser.setUsername( "serveradmin" );
        serverAdminUser.setPassword( "serveradmin" );
        serverAdminUser.addRole( serverAdmin );

        accountService.addUser( serverAdminUser );

        User normalUser = new User();
        normalUser.setFirstName( "Normal" );
        normalUser.setLastName( "User" );
        normalUser.setSex( Sex.Undefined );
        normalUser.setUsername( "normal" );
        normalUser.setPassword( "normal" );
        normalUser.addRole( normal );

        accountService.addUser( normalUser );

        context.close();
    }
}
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
{
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource( dataSource() );
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan( new String[] { "com.obsm.visensia.model" } );
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties( hibernateProperties() );
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName( environment.getRequiredProperty( "jdbc.driverClassName" ) );
    dataSource.setUrl( environment.getRequiredProperty( "jdbc.url" ) );
    dataSource.setUsername( environment.getRequiredProperty( "jdbc.username" ) );
    dataSource.setPassword( environment.getRequiredProperty( "jdbc.password" ) );
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put( "hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty( "hibernate.dialect" ) );
    properties.put( "hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty( "hibernate.show_sql" ) );
    properties.put( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" ) );
    properties.put( "hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty( "hibernate.format_sql" ) );
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager ( SessionFactory sessFact )
{
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory( sessFact );
    return transactionManager;
}
}
```

My LoginController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {
        HibernateConfig.InitialiseDummyData();
        model.addAttribute( "user", new User() );
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String verifyUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model)
    {
        if ( accountService.verifyUser( user.getUsername(), user.getPassword() ) ) {
            User usr = accountService.findUserByUsername( user.getUsername() );
            model.addAttribute( "message", "Welcome, " + usr.getFirstName() );
            return "hello";
        }
        else
            return "login";
    }
}
```

My HelloController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")//Doesn't work even if I change it to '/hello'
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Please help, I've been stuck here for 3 days now :'(

**UPDATE**

Jetty 9.2.4v20141103 and this is the stacktrace:

```
Jetty 9.2.4v20141103 and following is the stacktrace:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b833a897.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$30(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b833a897$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$56ff08f3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b833a897.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.obsm.visensia.configuration.HibernateConfig.InitialiseDummyData(HibernateConfig.java:32)
    at com.obsm.visensia.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

Added a class to initialise my db right after my context is refreshed, as thus:

```
@Component
public class DbInitialiserOnStartUp implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@Transactional
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent( ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent ) {
    if ( accountService != null )
    {
        //inserts etc...
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: Post the error message details (stacktrace if you have it)

Comment: Jetty 9.2.4v20141103, updated the stacktrace:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and it's working fine...try this:

```
// You named it WebConfig
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer { // web.xml replacement
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    // Here you need to change "io.shido.config" to your config location
    applicationContext.setConfigLocation("io.shido.config");

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
        new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext)); // Register and map the dispatcher servlet

    //servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.default", "development");
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext));
    //applicationContext.register(AppConfig.class); // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/web/*"); // ...and here also change the context
  }
}
```

Notice I'm using `/web` as my context also...so change it accordingly. There is sample project [here](https://bitbucket.org/vadimvera/spring-mvc/) in case you want to take a look; and [this](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-next-java-web-app-less-xml-no-long-restarts-fewer-hassles-part-1/) is really, really good article about the subject by the ZeroTurnaround guys.

Additionally, I have in my Maven POM file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <!--<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>-->
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**UPDATE**

Your Spring configuration is working fine (but you can really improve it a little bit more); the issue is in the `LoginController` on the line when you are calling `HibernateConfig.InitialiseDummyData();`. Comment that line and everything will be fine.

You are starting another Spring context when you call that method. I couldn't fix the issues with the database since I don't have your schema...better to use an in-memory database when doing *Proof of Concepts*. Try to improve/fix that piece of code and you should good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, machina! I tried it but same error. Also tried it with the source from your link (don't have 1.8, so had to target 1.7 to build) and that too doesn't work. If you want I can zip my project to you?

Comment: OK @KunalPatel ...put it on GitHub or somewhere similar...let's have a look and see what's wrong

Comment: @KunalPatel I updated the answer...it should be straightforward to fix it

Comment: @machina - Yes that does solve the problem partially, as in doesn't get the error. But that static method `InitialiseDummyData()` initialises some data for me in the database as I'm trying to test the login stuff, and to do that it accesses the `ApplicationContext`. Could you please suggest what is right way to access `context` such that it doesn't barfs like it does now? Thanks for helping, much appreciated. :-)

Comment: @KunalPatel move the `InitialiseDummyData` method to a Spring bean, mark it as `@Component`, for instance, and inject the service or DAO you need to access and store/retrieve data

Comment: Thank you very much for your direction! I finally did it using a `ContextRefreshedEvent` listener class. Is this the correct way to do it? Did try what you said, using Bean, but didn't quite get it. However, would be interested to know how it'd have been done the way said above. I'm marking your update as answer, shame I can't do more than that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {



    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig2.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```